# Is my USB SSD Unrepairable?

Tags: ssd

A couple of years ago I had a power cut whilst formatting (IIRC) a new 2TB USB SSD. I assumed it was 'bricked' without hope of recovery, and put it in a drawer.

I recently decided to dig it out and see if I could get it working.

After using a 'power cycling' technique, I can now get it to be 'seen' by the gdisk utility. I've been treading carefully (mainly in the dark!), but whatever I've tried the messages from gdisk report that there are 0 sectors and 0 bytes. This is the output from the 'p' command:

```
Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 0 sectors, 0 bytes
Model: Z3-2TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): FA182BC0-55EF-409B-8C66-306EC7BB5940
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 18446744073709551582
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number Start (sector) End (sector) Size Code Name
```

If I try creating a new partition and accept the defaults I get huge numbers, but still 0 sectors and bytes. I've also tried formatting the disk and zeroing it with:
`cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdb`
but in both cases gdisk reports that there is insufficient room on the disk.

Where do I go now - is the disk irrecoverably corrupted/bricked? I'd be grateful for any suggestions, please.

Jim

Comment: Looks like the hardware is stuffed. Before writing it off though, can you update the post with S.M.A.R.T results (or at least what happens when you try query it).  You wpuld alwaya expect the result of the catting /dev/zero to be that there is insufficient room, so wothout knowing how long it took to return that answer that does not tell us anyting, but the 0 byte size is a strong indicator it hosed.

Comment: Its a long shit but can you remove the drive from its housing and connect it up directly?  Its conceivable the issue is the usb to sata/nvme circuitry (but I think thats a bit unlikely)

Comment: Sounds like corrupt firmware.

Comment: I've given up on it thanks for the reply.